# Grab value from URL without page refresh or button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently created a form that will take youtube links and parse/regex extracts the ID.  The function is executed through a button click which then prints the ID of the `URL`. Is there a way to have it display the `ID` without a button click and a page refresh? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/testYTvid/test.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['ytinput'])){

function getYoutubeId($sYoutubeUrl) {

    # set to zero
    $youtube_id = "";
    $sYoutubeUrl = trim($sYoutubeUrl);

    # the User entered only the eleven chars long id, Case 1
    if(strlen($sYoutubeUrl) === 11) {
        $youtube_id = $sYoutubeUrl;
        return $sYoutubeUrl;
    }

    # the User entered a Url
    else {

        # try to get all Cases
        if (preg_match('~(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})~i', $sYoutubeUrl, $match)) {
            $youtube_id = $match[1];
            return $youtube_id;
        }
        # try to get some other channel codes, and fallback extractor
        elseif(preg_match('~http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?|embed\/([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})|watch\?v\=([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})|#.*/([0-9A-Za-z-_]{11})~si', $sYoutubeUrl, $match)) {

            for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
                if (strlen($match[$i])==11) {
                    $youtube_id = $match[$i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $youtube_id;
        }
        else {
            $youtube_id = "No valid YoutubeId extracted";
            return $youtube_id;
        }
    }
}


 print 'Result: ' . getYoutubeId($_POST['ytinput']);

}


?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ytinput" value="<? $sYoutubeUrl ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Parsen">
</form>
```

Comment: Really not clear what you want. What event triggers retrieving this ID, and what needs to be sent to server?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is using Ajax through Javascript.

Note this solution requires the use of the jQuery JavaScript library. See http://jquery.com/

Firstly we need to get the url from the form, by doing this:

```
var sYoutubeUrl = $('input [name="ytinput"]').val();
```

Then we need to make our Ajax request to your function file, and get the result.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<relative link to function file>/file.php',
        data: 'sYoutubeUrl='+sYoutubeUrl,

        //Catch the result
        success: function(response) {
            //Assign response to a variable
            var youtube_id = response;
            //Display response inside the form
            $('input [name="ytinput"]').val('youtube_id');
        },

    });
```

This is just a basic guide, you will need to change your php file slightly and also change your form from being a POST triggered form. Also you will need to put the JS I gave you inside a trigger event, likely on form submit like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   //Code above here
});
```